# Syntax Iptables and routing UDP protocol

Tags: debian, iptables, routing

I have a debian routeur server with two interfaces, one on the net, and one on the DMZ.

I want to route the UDP protocol to internet to DMZ.

What about this rules?

`iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -i [InternetInterfaces] -p udp 10000 -d 0.0.0.255 -j TEE --gateway IPOFDMZINTERFACE`

Thanks a lot for helping me.

Regards

Comment: `...route ...to internet to DMZ` so where do you want to route it? If you want to change the routing, why don't you do it through the means of routing (ie changing routes)?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, i want to route **from** internet to DMZ

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you rather need to NAT traffic from the Internet to DMZ. If that's the case, your `iptables` rule should look like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to <ip.of.dmz.host>
```

Also, make sure IP forwarding is enabled with

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, but i have allready done this nat rule without success:`root@SERVER:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:10000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             10.67.X.X          udp dpt:10000

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: These rules are wrong and redundant (chain policy is ACCEPT anyway). Note the 'nat' table and 'PREROUTING' / 'POSTROUTING' chain in my answer.